# PowerShell 'if' mechanism dependant on VM State

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm new to PowerShell and am trying to write a script that's dependant on a Hyper-V VM's status. Here's my (basic) if statement:

```
if((get-vm WMDC2 | out-string) -like '*Running*') { echo "running"}
```

I feel like there has to be a better way of doing this, but I don't know what it is. I don't think this is a bad way of doing it, but as I'm trying to learn, I'd like to know if there is a better way and if this *is* a bad way of doing this, why.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the first answer, my only idea was to convert to a string to check the object's properties against something I'm looking for. I'd like if there were a way to do this without converting my output to a string, and that is essentially what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Format-*`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlets (your `fl` is [`Format-List`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-5.1)) are to format output for view in the console. Do not re-parse them for values. Collect the object(s) returned by the `Get-VM` and access the properties directly.

```
# Get the VM object
$vm = Get-VM WMDC2
# check if the 'state' property equals 'Running'
if ($vm.state -eq 'Running') {
   Write-Host 'Running'
}
```

And if you absolutely do not want to store the VM object for some reason you can also shorthand it like this.

```
if ((Get-VM WMDC2).state -eq 'Running'){
  Write-Host 'Running'
}
```

> I don't think this is a bad way of doing it

It is a bad way of doing it, but it's not your fault. It's common that beginning Powershellers jump in and start trying to string-ify all the things. Without delving too far into Powershell objects, the worst part of this approach is that you lose the usefulness built-in (properties, methods, pipeline-ability) to the object returned by `Get-VM`.

Comment: I tagged the question as Hyper-V, but I'll add it to the question for clarity. I was unaware that PowerCLI was PowerShell compatible so I didn't think to specify. Also, I thought converting the one line I needed to a string would be better than converting the whole output to a string. Is there a way to optimize in that way? I realize that in this situation, the full list of properties is really short, but I'll eventually be working with things that have a great many more properties. On top of that, I'd like to be able to target specific properties rather than the whole output.

Comment: @MagnaVis PowerCLI is VMware's Powershell modules/console for working with vSphere and more.

Comment: Cool, I don't use VMware's offerings, so I had no idea. Thanks!

Comment: @MagnaVis Both my examples show how to only target the `state` property. I've change the `-like` to `-eq` to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for, thank you!